# PHP prepared statement while

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the original code

```
 <?php
$db = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' ) or die ('Connection to MYSQL server failed!');
mysql_select_db( 'pw', $db ) or die ('DB not found!');
$cubi = 500;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id IN(SELECT uid FROM point WHERE zoneid=1)");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
mysql_query("call usecash('".$row["ID"]."', '1', '0', '1', '0', '$cubi', '1', @error)");
};
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

I am trying to make this work with `prepared statements`. I was able to come up with this code.

```
<?php

class Jaden extends MainController{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->view->url    =   $this->config->url;
        $this->view->ID       = get_class($this);
        $this->view->Title = "Paradise JD > Ranking";
        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cashtable";
        $arr = array();
        $cash = $this->database->DBQry($sql, $arr);
        $userid = $cash[0]['userid'];
        $zoneid = $cash[0]['zoneid'];
        $jaden = $cash[0]['cash'];
        $cubi = 500;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id IN(SELECT uid FROM point WHERE zoneid=1)";
        $arr = array();
        while($row = $this->database->DBCtr($sql, $arr)){
            echo 'YES!!';

        }
   }
}

?>
```

After that the page just loads for 30 seconds and then says the following error.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

I don't know if I am using the `while` statement the right way or not.

---

**Prepared Statements**

```
        // Query
    function DBQry($sql,$arr){
        $sth = $this->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($arr);
        $rs = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $rs;
    }

    // Count
    function DBCtr($sql,$arr){
        $sth = self::prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($arr);
        return $sth->rowCount();
    }
```

Comment: What is $this->database? And how does the DBCtr/DBQry methods look like?

Comment: what does `DBCtr()` do

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to include the prepared statements.

Comment: Why do you have a `;` after your `}`?

Comment: @Ibu I added the statements.

Comment: `DBCtr` returns an int, why are you trying to loop over that?  Perhaps you wanted `while($row = $this->database->DBQry($sql, $arr)){`?  Looping with `DBCtr` would just create an infinite loop.

Comment: I used `DBQry` as well and it still did the same thing

Comment: DBQry returns an array, have a look at `foreach` or something. Also, this have nothing to do with prepared statements. (More than you are using `prepare`)

Comment: Would `foreach` work with what I am trying to do?

Comment: Your `while` is calling `DBCtr` (or `DBQry`) over and over again.  It's returning the same result, and then it's looping again, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Actually it is assigning every time `=`, try `==`. Or am I totally off here?

Comment: OH, that would make sense why it gives that error.

Comment: @dollarvar: See example 2 here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php.  `fetch()` returns the next row or NULL.  So, you're setting `$row` to the row and then checking if it's NULL.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah, but he is not checking, he is assigning?!? Additionaly to checking an integer. ;)

Comment: @dollarvar: Yes, he's assigning (the result of the `=` operator is the value assigned), because he thought his code was like the example I posted in my previous comment.  He's using `fetchAll` instead of `fetch()`, so this does not work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ok, give me a moment to check all that through. Ok, so he could leave the `$row =` out, same thing?

Comment: @dollarvar: `while($row = $stmt->fetch())` works because `fetch()` returns the next row each time it's called (it returns a *different* value each time it's called).  That array is assigned to `$row`, and since an array is "truthy", the loop runs.  When there are no more rows, `fetch()` returns NULL.  That is set to `$row`, and since NULL is "falsy", the loop stops.  In the OP's case, his functions were returning the *same* value over and over so he got an infinite loop.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ok, yeah, got it, the one query run infinitely because returning an integer, and the other was on `fetchAll` still running infinitely. Just one question again (you might have missed my update):so he could leave the `$row =` out, same thing?

Comment: @dollarvar: You *could* leave out `$row =`, the loop would run the same, but then you couldn't read the value returned by the function.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You mean you cannot use `$row` in the `while` loop?

Comment: @dollarvar: Yeah, you can't use `$row` in the loop if you never set it ;)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hehe, yeah, got it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the `while` statement to a `foreach` statement and used the following code.

```
            foreach ($user as $usr){
            $arr = array(":userid" => $usr['ID'], ":zoneid" => 1, ":sn" => 0, ":aid" => 1, ":point" => 0, ":cash" => 50, ":status" => 1, ":creatime" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $this->database->DBIns($arr, 'usecashnow');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
while($row = $this->database->DBCtr($sql, $arr)){
```

You are calling `DBCtr` each time the loop runs.  `DBCtr` returns an int, and unless it's `0`, the loop runs.  Then you call `DBCtr` *again* with the same query, it's still not `0`, so the loop runs.  Thus infinite loop.

Even changing `DBCtr` to `DBQry` won't work here, since you will just keep running the same query over and over.

You need to use a `foreach` here instead of a `while`.  You can only use a `while` loop with `fetch()` (*not* with `fetchAll`), because when you call it over and over, it returns the next row (or NULL when there are no more rows).

```
foreach($this->database->DBQry($sql, $arr) as $row){
```